# How migrat values from one foreign Key to another SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm working on a data migration from one database to a another.

So far everything is working but with one table I always get the same error. There is a problem with the foreign key that I also want to migrate in this table. I think I have to declare something special for a foreign key?

This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO [asd].HolidayTracker.dbo.AnnualVacation(UserId,WorkingTime,VacationDays,FromDate,ToDate)
SELECT u1.user_htUserId,
       u1.vacationDays,
       u1.workingTime,
       CAST('2013-01-01' AS DATETIME),
       CAST('2013-12-31' AS DATETIME)

FROM    HolidayTracker.dbo.AnnualVacation u1 
            LEFT JOIN  [asd].HolidayTracker.dbo.AnnualVacation u2
                ON u1.user_htUserId = u2.UserId AND 
                   u1.vacationDays = u2.VacationDays AND
                   u1.workingTime = u2.WorkingTime
```

This is the error message I get:

```
error message INSERT INTO [asd].HolidayTracker.dbo.AnnualVacation(UserId,WorkingTime,VacationDays‌​,FromDate,ToDate) – `
```

This is the table structure:
Source table

[image]

Destination table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For starters you have the WorkingTime, VacationDays fields the wrong way around in the insert statement compared to the fields you are selecting.

Try changing the order of the fields, like below, and see what happens.

The error could be as simple as you trying to insert the float into the int column and your not casting the value.

```
INSERT INTO [asd].HolidayTracker.dbo.AnnualVacation(UserId,VacationDays,WorkingTime,FromDate,ToDate)
SELECT u1.user_htUserId,
   u1.vacationDays,
   u1.workingTime,
   CAST('2013-01-01' AS DATETIME),
   CAST('2013-12-31' AS DATETIME)

FROM    HolidayTracker.dbo.AnnualVacation u1 
        LEFT JOIN  [asd].HolidayTracker.dbo.AnnualVacation u2
            ON u1.user_htUserId = u2.UserId AND 
               u1.vacationDays = u2.VacationDays AND
               u1.workingTime = u2.WorkingTime
```

Comment: same problem The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AnnualVacation_HtUser1". The conflict occurred in database "HolidayTracker", table "dbo.HtUser", column 'UserId'.